# words is only replaced one time

Tags: javascript

here is my code

```
</script>
  function myFunction() {
   var a = ["a.m.","p.m","u.k."];
   var b = ["its_morning","its_noon","unKnown_thing"];
   var str = document.getElementById("textBox1").value;
      for (var k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
        str = str.replace(a[k], b[k]); 
                                         };
   document.getElementById('textBox2').value = str;
     }
</script>

<body>

  <textarea onkeyup="myFunction();"id="textBox1"></textarea>
  <TEXTAREA type="text" id="textBox2"></TEXTAREA>
</body>
```

when i type 'a.m.' its working fine but when i type it again its not changing . 
like:

> 'a.m. hello world  a.m.'

gives results

> 'its_morning hello world  a.m.'

here the last 'a.m.' must be replaced but i dont know wats wrong with it

please answer in javascript ,im not familiar with jquery.

Comment: @AlexK.  i tried that one it has problem with dots '.'

Comment: See the bit about `escapeRegExp`

Comment: i dont know why but nothing is printing in textbox2 while using this `escapeRegExp` thing

Comment: i will go with @amitjoki 's method .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`String.replace(String, String)` just replaces the first occurence.

You can use the regex with "g" modifier so it replaces every occurence. Since, it is dynamic string, you should use `RegExp` constructor.

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp(a[k].replace(/\./g, '\\.'),"g"), b[k]);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will match "aim", because of the `.` or any character in the middle

Comment: i tried this one it has two problems one is : the case insensetive proble and the second is : it takes 'a.m.' and 'akmk' as same thing.

Comment: @Nakul case-insensitive is not applied, so it is not a problem

Comment: @AmitJoki i tried this and i want case sensitive replacement .

Comment: Downvotes? Really after the edit?? Great!

Comment: @AmitJoki i think your way is more sufficient way to do this thing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the replace will not replaceAll automatically. You have to use global regex for this.

eg instead of writing

`string.replace("search","replace")`

write:

`string.replace(/search/g,"replace")`

The /g flags means searching globally, eg replaceAll

In your case, I would write the a array as an array of regexes instead:

`var a = [
   /a\.m\./g,
   /p\.m/g,
   /u\.k\./g
];`

However, you need to escape special characters, like `.`

Your code should than be:

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
   var a = [
      /a\.m\./g,
      /p\.m/g,
      /u\.k\./g
   ];
   var b = ["its_morning","its_noon","unKnown_thing"];
   var str = document.getElementById("textBox1").value;
      for (var k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
        str = str.replace(a[k], b[k]); 
                                         };
   document.getElementById('textBox2').value = str;
     }
</script>
```

Comment: hey @edi9999  can i use string.replace(a[k]/g,b[k]);

Comment: That wouldn't work, JS would think that you're tring to divide a[k] by g. Why are you asking this ?

Comment: because im working with arrays

Comment: You can write it like this : `var a = [/a\.m\./g,/p\.m/g,/u\.k\./g];`

Comment: are you replaceing these [] brackets with these weird chars

Comment: /test/g is a shorthand for writing new RegExp("test",g)

Comment: please edit my question code so i can understand it easy way,

Comment: Done. Hope that helps

Comment: thanks edi  , but what if i want to add more words in my array'a'   sorry its taking too long but please help me to do this

Comment: You will need to write /string/g instead of "string", and add a "\" before any of the following characters: `.?*+^$\(){}|-`